# Is there any front-end architecture specifically well suited for building sites with sitecore?

Tags: javascript, architecture, content-management-system, sitecore, frontend

Brand new to sitecore, don't have a solid grasp of what the site we are building looks like functionality wise, but curious to get opinions, pros and cons, articles that might have helped others, and the like. I've heard angular isn't too well suited to interact with sitecore, also read about reactJS.net being well suited.

Specifically, does anyone have experience to share on prebuild tools; css preprocessors; and javascript frameworks, templating tools, or libraries  that have integrated well into sitecore, or ones that have integrated very poorly?

I hope this isn't too broad, I guess in my wild dream I'm imagining someone with extensive experience with sitecore itching to share their vast knowledge on their front end architecture...

Comment: For this kind of questions/discussion you can better use https://community.sitecore.net/

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore's content model fits very nicely with MVC concepts - for each sublayout/rendering (widget) you have a datasource referenced by an ID, and some parameters to modify presentation.

This means that by logically anything that works well with .Net MVC should work well with Sitecore.

Additionally there's also a [Sitecore REST API](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc66-71-usletter.pdf) that will enable you to use various Javascript frontends without needing to implement a lot of serverside mapping code.

Beyond those points you can treat it like you would any other data driven .Net Web App.